# PHP Fatal error: Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to upload files to a live server, but I am getting this error.

> PHP Fatal error: Trait
>   'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents' not found in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 25

I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: have you ran `composer install` on the live server?

Comment: yes , all files working fine in local file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run the **composer dump-autoload**

Comment: i update composer and run the command composer dump-autoload .